# importing a file as a package - Python

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
/testlib
    __init__.py
    ec2.py
    unit/
       __init__.py
       test_ec2.py
    utils/
       __init__.py
```

I'm trying to create a `unittest` class for `ec2.py`:

```
import ec2

class TestEC2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ec2obj = ec2.EC2(name="testlib_unittest")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, when I execute `test_ec2.py` I'm getting the following error:

```
python unit/test_ec2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit/test_ec2.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ec2
ImportError: No module named ec2
```

I still don't understand why I'm getting that, since I have the `__init__.py` properly set in the directory. The  `__init__.py` files are completely empty: I've created them with `touch __init__.py`. Any clues?

**** Updates ****
Here are some suggestions:

```
/testlib# python unit/test_ec2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit/test_ec2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..ec2 import EC2
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

testlib# python unit/test_ec2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit/test_ec2.py", line 4, in <module>
    import testlib.ec2 as ec2
ImportError: No module named testlib.ec2
```

Comment: What does your `__init__.py` look like?

Comment: @Zizouz212 it's empty ...

Comment: Have you tried doing `import testlib.ec2`?

Comment: `from ..ec2 import EC2`

Comment: @Nsh see the question update.

Comment: That looks strange? Is the entire thing in your `sys.path`?

Comment: @Zizouz212 no, it's not on `sys.path`, however for portability I would like to have that code to be executed without having to manually set `sys.path`

Comment: Where's @MartijnPieters now? :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't find the module because you're running the script incorrectly. Run the following in `testlib/`:

```
python -m unit.test_ec2
```

Comment: Yep - that would do it. Also if you don't go a level up you can specify the python path. PYTHONPATH=/home/path/to/testlib/ python unit/test_ec2.py

Answer (score 0):

Python is not looking for files in directories above yours. Ignacio's answer is correct, and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) for elaboration.